# Network cable unplugged after updating to 17.10

Tags: networking, drivers, updates

I updated my Ubuntu from version 17.04 to 17.10 and now if I plug in the network cable to one of my network card it shows that the cable is unplugged. I use a router and have two network card and I would like to use the Realtek integrated card.

I installed the Realtek driver without success. How can I fix the problem? Here are some information that maybe can help you in the diagnostics:

UPDATE:
I deleted the wired network profiles, because I had a lot and now at the Settings -> Network tab the Wired section disappeared.

**lspci -nnk**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 82P965/G965 Memory Controller Hub [8086:29a0] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 82P965/G965 Memory Controller Hub [1462:7235]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82P965/G965 PCI Express Root Port [8086:29a1] (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2834] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P965 Neo MS-7235 mainboard [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2835] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:283a] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:284b] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:283f] (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:2849] (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2830] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P965 Neo MS-7235 mainboard [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2831] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P965 Neo MS-7235 mainboard [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2832] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:2836] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P965 Neo MS-7235 mainboard [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev f2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801HB/HR (ICH8/R) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2810] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 82801HB/HR (ICH8/R) LPC Interface Controller [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) 4 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:2820] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P965 Neo MS-7235 mainboard [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:283e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P965 Neo MS-7235 mainboard [1462:7235]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HR/HO/HH (ICH8R/DO/DH) 2 port SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:2825] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P965 Neo MS-7235 mainboard [1462:7235]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix
    Kernel modules: pata_acpi
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] [10de:0402] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] [1043:825c]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
03:00.0 IDE interface [0101]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE6121 SATA II / PATA Controller [11ab:6121] (rev b1)
    Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE6121 SATA II / PATA Controller [11ab:6121]
    Kernel driver in use: pata_marvell
    Kernel modules: ahci, pata_marvell, pata_acpi
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Accton Technology Corporation EN-1216 Ethernet Adapter [1113:1216] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Standard Microsystems Corp [SMC] EN-1216 Ethernet Adapter [10b8:a255]
    Kernel driver in use: tulip
    Kernel modules: tulip
04:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet [10ec:8167] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] P965 Neo MS-7235 mainboard [1462:235c]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  6
appletalk              36864  0
ipx                    28672  0
p8023                  16384  1 ipx
psnap                  16384  2 appletalk,ipx
p8022                  16384  1 ipx
gpio_ich               16384  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec_realtek    94208  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
coretemp               16384  0
rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2x00usb              20480  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib             114688  1 rt2800usb
snd_hda_intel          40960  8
rt2x00lib              53248  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
r8169                  45056  0
snd_hda_codec         126976  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
mac80211              778240  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
cfg80211              610304  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
serio_raw              16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  25 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
lpc_ich                24576  0
shpchp                 36864  0
mac_hid                16384  0
iptable_filter         16384  0
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             28672  1 ip6table_filter
br_netfilter           24576  0
bridge                143360  1 br_netfilter
stp                    16384  1 bridge
llc                    16384  4 p8022,psnap,bridge,stp
arp_tables             24576  0
parport_pc             32768  1
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               40960  5 arp_tables,ip_tables,iptable_filter,ip6table_filter,ip6_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
psmouse               147456  0
pata_acpi              16384  0
tulip                  65536  0
nouveau              1638400  26
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
pata_marvell           16384  0
ahci                   36864  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    24576  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    94208  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 nouveau
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
floppy                 77824  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
drm                   356352  26 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

**ifconfig -a**

```
enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::204:e2ff:fe7a:fe06  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:04:e2:7a:fe:06  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 7  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 14  collisions 0

enp4s2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.104  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::219:dbff:fef4:3a63  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:19:db:f4:3a:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 285873  bytes 421636228 (421.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 103726  bytes 7640122 (7.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 21  base 0x9800  

enp4s0:avahi: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.8.77  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether 00:04:e2:7a:fe:06  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2088  bytes 176236 (176.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2088  bytes 176236 (176.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx74ea3a8e73ad: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::5f7d:70c4:d9ad:9e98  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 74:ea:3a:8e:73:ad  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 105  bytes 7782 (7.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 181  bytes 19248 (19.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp4s2 iface
iface enp4s2 inet dhcp

auto enp4s0 iface
iface enp4s0 inet dhcp
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it's started working and I did just a few simple modification.

1. I reinstalled the Realtek network card driver
2. I modified the /etc/network/interfaces and deleted the rows which are related to enp4s0 and enp4s2. So now it's looks like this:

`# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`

3. Restarted my computer.